# Crash issue in LPMessagingSDK iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have integrated LPMessagingSDK in my iOS application. When I start chat for the first time. It works as expected. But If I kill the application and relaunch it again. It is crashing with below crash log.

Please help me out.

> Crashed: SQLQueue 0x10675e690 for Consumer.sqlite
>   _T07LPInfra17OverflowingBufferC7sendAll33_3B6C015BA679803417E3C34F44AA327CLL10Fo
>   50 myApp 0x104a0e634 -[AppDelegate
>   application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:]
>   (AppDelegate.m:667)

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken { 
  [[LPMessagingSDK instance] registerPushNotificationsWithToken:deviceToken notificationDelegate:self alternateBundleID:nil]; 
  [NotificationService.sharedService processPossiblyNewDeviceToken:deviceToken]; 
  [self sendAPNsToken]; 
  [NotificationService.sharedService setupInAppNotifications];

 }
```

Comment: pls also share part of code at AppDelegate.m:667

Comment: Using below code to register APNS.                                                                      - (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    [[LPMessagingSDK instance] registerPushNotificationsWithToken:deviceToken notificationDelegate:self alternateBundleID:nil];
    [NotificationService.sharedService processPossiblyNewDeviceToken:deviceToken];
    [self sendAPNsToken];
    [NotificationService.sharedService setupInAppNotifications];
}

Comment: what your sendAPNsToken methed do.. are you save device token any other data to Sqlite DB ?

Comment: which of method run sqlite query to save data ...its may be about unspecified impacts that happened when multiple time query hit in loop with open&close statement of sqlite.

Comment: Issue has been resloved, It is due to LPMessaging SDK old version 2.8.0.1. After upgrading to latest version. It is working. @MAhipalSingh